# Why does using in text scripting cause XSS error?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf, xss

I have this code that runs and gets a value when searched. However, I noticed that one can do cross site script attack on a particular part of the code. I found out using [ZAP](https://owasp.org/www-project-zap/). How can I stop this or improve the way I get my values? Is `th:utext="${query} ?: ''"` bad?

Display on search page:

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="col-12">You searched for: </h1> <span th:utext="${query} ?: ''"></span>
  <p class="col-12">Found <span th:utext="${#lists.size(results)}">0</span> results</p>
</div>
```

Insert form:

```html
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search" method="get">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q"
    th:value="${query} ?: ''">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: probably because you put user supplied query directly here `You searched for: </h1> <span th:utext="${query}`

Comment: Why are you using `utext` (**u**nescaped **text**)?